# Garu kamma explanation

Tags: theravada, karma

garu-kamma (weighty karma) - if one has killed one's mother or father, for example. These types of karma outweigh any other possible result; one who has performed these at some time in this life cannot help but go to hell in their next existence.

This is a quote from Ven Yuttadhammos answer.

My question is does garu kamma relate to murder of ones parents or could it also be a reason to shame them which drives them to suicide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decision to commit suicide is an individual decision. So it does not cause Garuka kamma for the one who does the shaming unless one had the intention to make them commit suicide.

There are also Garuka Kusala Karmas like Jhanas and Maggapala.

Answer (score 0):

Killing your parents is a Anathariy Karma. 
This is worse than Garuka Karma.

Instrumenting this directly or indirectly results in the same Karma.

Bottom line is that you should be always good to your parents.

Comment: So people who decide to ordain and their parents who take it personally still qualifies as Anathariy Kamma?

Comment: If you are instrumental in doing this you gain a lot of good Karma. It is said that if you keep your parents on your shoulders and serve them you cannot repay your debts to them. If they are weak in morality and you help them get established in morality, if they are moral and you help them get established in mastery over the mind and if they have mastery over the mind and you help them get wisdom them you have repaid the debt you have to them.

Comment: Volition is what counts. This combined with so way to instrument the outcome cause the Karma. The thought itself is bad Karma. So you should not think about negative things like this.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you do it or scheme so others would do it or they do it themselves. If you have the slightest motivate or volition you get bad karma for bad intentions. Opposite if your intentions are good.

Comment: Also if you have done any of the 5 grave offenses you cannot ordain.

Comment: I think i was just wondering about them not being easy on themselves. I am certain it won't go to a drastic extreme.

Comment: Good. Try to develop genuine Metta towards them and try to help them out in getting out of the hard times and then establish themselves in the Dhamma.

Comment: You need to get your parents permission to ordain also.

Comment: I think I miss read the 1st comment. But best is to do it peacefully and tactfully as possible also giving them the opportunity to develop in the Dhamma.

Comment: Actually it's both an ānantariya kamma and a garuka kamma.